# About two events being mutually exclusive and independent give that one of the event's probability is zero.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm studying statistics and probability using an introductory textbook and it had this question:

[image]

```
108.The events “Other” and “Up for reelection in November 2016” are ________

a. mutually exclusive.

b. independent.

c. both mutually exclusive and independent.

d. neither mutually exclusive nor independent.
```

The answer key says that the correct answer is letter *a*, but shouldn't it be letter *c* as the P("Other" $\cap$ "Up for reelection in November 2016") = 0 meaning that the two events are mutually exclusive and that the P("Other"|"Up for reelection in November 2016") = P(Other), therefore also being independent?

Comment: You can't be mutually exclusive as well as independent.  If $A$ and $B$ are m.e., then knowledge of $A$ definitely means that $B$ didn't happen, so they aren't independent.

Comment: If A and B are events and if P(A) = 0, then if two events are mutually exclusive then, P(A AND B) = 0, therefore P(A|B) = P(A), doesn't that mean it's independent too?

Comment: I suppose so, but I don't think impossible events give any deep interpretations.

Comment: I now just read the entire question (sorry).  Seems like an odd question. In your case, what is the situation with $P(B \mid A)$?  Is this also $P(B)$?

Comment: I just thought about it and P(B | A) would end up being undefined. Does that mean that there are no mutually exclusive events that are independent because if P(A) and/or P(B) were zero it would result to being undefined?

Comment: Is the better definition of independent $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$?  Does this make it clear that they are in fact independent?

Comment: Yes, isn't that one of the three conditions that have to be met for events to be independent?

Comment: To me, that's the *only* condition for independence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93898/discussion-between-user65141-and-randall).

Comment: I’m confused about what is being viewed as the sample space, and what is the structure of an outcome? And what is the probability model?

Comment: @Michael I think it's a poorly set-up problem, at least what I can see here.

Comment: Whether you are up for re-election clearly does depend on party affiliation.